# Kibana not showing ANYTHING except for Timelion

Tags: nginx, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I recently re-installed my ELK stack to a cloud server instead of a local box, and I am running into a slew of issues with Kibana.

Everything is set up correctly, my indexes ARE being created from Elasticsearch(you can see them with the `http://<ip-of-ELK>:9200/_cat/indices?v` command. Kibana *is* an index that shows up.

Here is what happened the first time that I got to Kibana:

1. The normal page showed up to type in an index to represent
2. I type in filebeat-* , and then hit create
3. Server error, Kibana was not started properly
4. I do the `systemctl reset-failed kibana`  and `systemctl restart kibana`  on my server, because I didn't see anything in my error log for Kibana.

And now, I cannot see anything in Kibana except for the 'Timelion' tab, which

[image: Timelion shows up]

[image: Nothing else does]

Different broswers don't work either.

Running ELK 5.2
CentOS 7 is the host system

Comment: What if you try and run another instance of `Kibana` (on a different port) on top of same `ES` instance which you're running?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a reverse proxy?

I had a very similar error when using nginx  until I found a working config. See below for a working nginx config that may help you out. You may need different rewrites depending on versions and config used.

```
worker_processes 1; events { worker_connections 1024; } http { server { listen 80; server_name localhost; # redirect / location = / { rewrite ^ /_plugin/kibana/ redirect; } location / { proxy_pass https://<es-domain-url>.es.amazonaws.com; proxy_http_version 1.1; proxy_set_header Authorization ""; proxy_hide_header Authorization; proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme; auth_basic "Restricted"; auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htpasswd.users; } } }
```

Comment: This did not work either, I am STILL having this same problem. I uninstalled/reinstaleld nginx and kibana several times and tried tons of confs